# Power BI DAX formulae divide and subtract together

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-datasource

Kindly advice on DAX formulae  for calculating divide and subtract together

I have Column A, B, C
Formulae for calculating % as follow
Colum A / (Column B-C)
OR 
A/(B-C)
Any advice on how to convert this into DAX formulae will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For subtraction,  I was thinking this Dax formula:     Calculate (Sum(column[B]))-Calculate (Sum(column[C]))   but I need to combine this with  column A

Comment: Is this for a measure or for a calculated column? What you write will be different in these cases.

Comment: Getting an error please see attac

Comment: C      A B  Discount  DAX  Fomulae in %
49 33 30  C /(Column A- Culumn B)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the DIVIDE function instead of just regular division, because this handles scenarios where the denominator is null or zero, so I would use the following for your problem (when the denominator is zero, the output of this is 0):

```
MeasureName:=DIVIDE(Column A, Column B - Column C, 0)
```

Comment: Wow that’s really great much appreciated for  prompt response @ Tysonwright